# How do I enable 'Push to Remote' in Xcode 10?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode10

Where/how can I enable the 'Push to Remote' Option under 'Source Control' in Xcode 10 when I disabled this when I first created the project?

[image]

When I create a repository I get the following message:

[image]

Comment: There is no remote. Add one if you want to be able to push to it

Comment: How do I go about this though?

Comment: In the Source Control navigator

Comment: It does not let me it shows the error message attached

Comment: You didn’t do what I said. I didn’t say create a repository. I said add a remote.

Comment: matt did not listen

Answer (score 3):

To add a remote repository:

Under the Version control tab next to file browser tab, right click on your local repository and click 'Create Remote'.

Remote Name should be 'origin'. Give it a name, description and set Visibility.